# Calling REST api from angular2

Tags: node.js, rest, angular

I've finished the angular2 heroies tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ and now I'am trying to call a ral REST api that i've made with Node, Postgresql and Express.

The angular2 code calling the API looks like this:

...

```
export class HeroService{

  private heroesUrl = 'http://192.168.4.13:3000/api/boxes'; //URL til api
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
     .toPromise()
     .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
     .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

...

The browser console shows:

An error occurred Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null

[Picture from REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdlzY.png)

And I can see that my API isen't being called.
Any ideas to what I'am missing out?

Best regards.

Comment: The error message suggests that you got the URL wrong, i.e. it returns `404`. If you are also trying to call `.json()` on the `response` then it will fail because the content is not JSON. What is the API URL that you are trying to call? How did you define that API at the server side?

Comment: Unfortunately the API isen't public available, but I've updated my post with a picture, so that you can see the structure of the result from the API.

Comment: This might be silly, but have you tried removing the `http://` part from the URL? Also, can you open the browser console, select the network tab and refresh the page where you expect this to be called. That might help with understanding the problem better.

Comment: Then it results in a http 500: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL: null

Comment: Can you post the pictures of the browser console -> network with this API call selected? Also, how are you running the angular2 server? Is it served by the same backend, i.e. do they have the same domain?

Comment: When opening the network tab in the browser console, the call to the API dosen't show up.. They are both served from the same host (192.168.4.13).

Comment: After removing the http:// part, besides throwing the error above, it now says: "unable to parse url '192.168.4.13:3000/api/boxes'; original error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

I figurd out that I needed to remove these lines for the backend to be called:

```
// Imports for faking the http service - in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule }  from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }   from './in-memory-data.service';
```

I thought that Angular2 would ignore them when not being used, but the caused the new backend API not to being called.